# Why Mahabharata or Ramayana did not considered as earlier civilisation than IVC?

Tags: myth-identification, comparative, mythohistory, history, hindu

As we all know IVC is the first civilisation in India between 3300 to 1300 BCE. But Mahabharata and Ramayana should dated before this period based on Yuga cycle. Then we haven’t considered these are early civilisation?

Comment: The Yuga cycle cannot be used to reliably date historical events (assuming that the events described in Ramayana and Mahabharata are historical at all, which is very much open to debate)

Comment: Thank you for your comment